# Increase search efficiency using concurrency

Tags: go, search, concurrency, goroutine

I have the two following methods for searching for files with a name pattern (e.g. `*.go` for finding all go files) under a search path (e.g. `/Users/username/Desktop`). The first method uses recursion + goroutine, and the second method uses a queue to prevent possible stack overflow problem. From my testing on my own computer `Desktop` that has 41,233 go files, the first method beats the second method by 4 seconds, which are 18 and 22 seconds, respectively.

I was wondering if there is any better way/parallelism to make the search even more efficient, because I am integrating the search in a desktop app, and I don't want the user sitting there and wait for 30 seconds before seeing any search results.

```
type FileSearcher struct {
    Contents []MyFile
}

func (fe *FileSearcher) FindFileRecursive(searchPath, namePattern string) (err error) {

    // get absolute path
    if searchPath, err = filepath.Abs(searchPath); err != nil {
        return
    }
    curFileName := filepath.Base(searchPath)
    if matched, err := filepath.Match(namePattern, curFileName); err == nil && matched {
        if foundFile, err := NewFileFromPath(searchPath); err == nil {
            fe.Contents = append(fe.Contents, *foundFile) // found a match
        }
    } else {
        return
    }

    if isDir, _ := utils.IsDirectory(searchPath); isDir {
        if files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(searchPath); err == nil {
            for _, f := range files {
                fPath := filepath.Join(searchPath, f.Name())
                go fe.FindFileRecursive(fPath, namePattern) // recursive in a goroutine here
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

// FindFile searches for files/directories matching namePattern under searchPath
func (fe *FileSearcher) FindFile(searchPath, namePattern string) (err error) {

    queue := make([]string, 0)
    queue = append(queue, searchPath)

    for len(queue) > 0 {
        path := queue[0]
        curFileName := filepath.Base(path) // get the file/directory name at this path
        queue = queue[1:]                  // pop off the head

        if matched, err := filepath.Match(namePattern, curFileName); err == nil && matched {
            if foundFile, err := NewFileFromPath(path); err == nil {
                fe.Contents = append(fe.Contents, *foundFile) // found a match
            }
        }

        if isDir, _ := utils.IsDirectory(path); isDir {
            if files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path); err == nil {
                for _, f := range files {
                    fPath := filepath.Join(path, f.Name())
                    queue = append(queue, fPath) // push the new dir path to queue
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Unless you index the files ahead of time, you're constrained by your storage IO, in which case linear search is usually most efficient.

Comment: @JimB Unless you're on SSD in which case queue depth 8 is the sweet spot.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to read the code of ripgrep, which is written in Rust. It has some of the most efficient directory recursion and file search around.

Comment: @ZanLynx [this git repo](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). thanks

Comment: @ZanLynx: yeah, I guess "usually" doesn't cut it any longer ;)  I wasn't familiar with "8" being the common sweet spot, but as with anything performance related it should be tested, and this example should be trivial to change to an adjustable pool of workers to benchmark the concurrency levels.

Comment: @JimB Yeah this stuff changes all the time. Who knows, maybe in 2 years the sweet spot will be 256 or something.

Comment: Your target should be something along the lines of how long it takes "find" to find the files from the command line.  18 seconds seems incredibly slow for matching within 42k files.  Avoiding a recursive solution also seems like it could be a premature optimisation too (how much recursion is there really?). You might be better doing the match inline if it's a normal file and only recursing if it's a directory though.

Comment: Besides the 42k go files, there are 10 - 15 times more other files under the search path I used.